# Embedded FleetDB with Clojure 1.3

Tags: clojure, fleetdb

I'm trying to embedded the latest FleetDB to app using Clojure 1.3. I think because of the absent of contrib, it won't work anymore.

Has anybody here got Clojure 1.3 working with embedded Fleetdb and if you do can I see your project.clj ?

Comment: Probably you should post more details. Like some code, your tries at project.clj, did it work with previous versions of clojure, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Can't answer your question specifically as I haven't used FleetDB.

However the following page is very useful for seeing what happened to the various parts of contrib:  http://dev.clojure.org/display/design/Where+Did+Clojure.Contrib+Go

I suspect that it would be possible using the above to get your project.clj right for 1.3.